# errors updating Android Studio for targetSDK34

Tags: android, compiler-errors, compilation, targetsdkversion

As Android requires I update targetSDK to 34 I've run into an error I don't know how to find and fix.
I use the toptoche searchable spinner 1.3.1 and have never had an issue, now after making the changes in my gradle for target"comSDK34 I get this error,

org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1.

Understanding what to do is beyond my limited self taught abilities, any pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? To use 34 you need Hedgehog or newer (see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#api-level-support)). For some reason Giraffe still shows a warning about it, but it's safe to ignore if you aren't ready to update to 34. Android does *not* currently require using targetSdk of 34. There is a difference between a warning in the gradle file and an error/requirement.

Comment: I'm using giraffe, latest update. I got a message from the android saying my app needs to be 34+ compliant after 31 Aug 23 in order to post or update apps. Not being all that literate in AS I did my usual follow the auto update steps. Now I get that error and I can't compile.  As the app was mainly made for personal use I like to at least be able to compile my changes and tweaks. I can't even do that

Comment: API 34 is definitely not required yet, the Aug 2023 deadline said all apps need to be at API 33. If you are getting an actual error, look in the build tab to see if there is more info, and try using API 33. API 34 is not supported in Giraffe yet. API 34 (Android 14) is not even released yet - that's the upcoming dev version. Have a look [here](https://apilevels.com/) or on the official page [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk)

Comment: Went to project structure and changed everything back to 33, stilling getting same error. Tried 31 same error. I have probably really buggered something up. Probably best if I open up my zipped back up I made a few months back and see what the result are with that. I made that backup right as I made the bundle for the play store. Thank for your suggestions